# "manuscript" vs "article"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I (a Japanese speaker) have been editing a mathematical coterie magazine which will be distributed in a school (university) festival.

My question is below;
1. How should I, **as an editor**, call the collected "manuscripts" from writers?---"manuscripts" or "articles"?
I'm confused because once papers through proofreading and have been published, the papers become "an article", but "manuscript" also has a meaning "a completed (yet first) version of papers" (cf. [Collin's Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manuscript)) and also "article" is used like "write an article (not completed)".
2. For a "manuscript" becoming to be an "article", proofreading must be needed?
Or when should I use "manuscript", not "article" (of course vice versa)?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You should be able to see the difference if you look up both words in the dictionary. If this doesn't solve your problem then [edit] your question.

Comment: @Laurel Thank you for commenting. I'll edit (or delete) my questions later (not so quickly, because I have much to do today).

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: A manuscript is also an article (at its manuscript stage). So "article" should work for all purposes. "Articles in manuscript form" and "Articles ready for publication". HTH.

Comment: See also [writers.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, In your case, you would use manuscript as an editor.

For Q2, it really depends on who you are and with whom you talk for choosing it. It’s your preference when talking, most of the time. But be more careful with writing. I believe you know manuscript is first, handwritten or typed document; article is  a published document or a complete piece of writing, as a report or essay, that is part of a newspaper, magazine, or book.

The example you listed, “write an article ( not completed).” I I think the possible ways to get that meaning is you’re in progress or you’re stating something.

Eg. He is writing an article ( not completed). 
      Finish this article by Friday.
      Writing an article is difficult.

However, I’m not familiar with publication “rules”. So I’m not sure if you need proofread every time before you publish the articles. But if you look carefully enough, you would notice that manuscript is used before publication and article must be published according to the definitions from Collins dictionary.

Just seeing that manuscript is the original version of an article.
Hopefully, my explanation will help you. Good luck with editing!

Comment: I'm really sorry for delay of the reply.  Thank you so much!